# javascript, mysql database and escaping 'weird' characters

Tags: javascript, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, escaping

On my website visitors can do some inline editing. I use ajax for it with a MySQL database and PHP. I expect the Dutch language to be used on the website.

My challenge is to get the character encoding to work well.

I could use advice on:

- the database (do i use utf-8? latin1_swedish_ci)
- the tables in the database (i'd prefer to heve them similar to the database.)
- the escaping to use in the ajax call (x = escape(x);)
- the webpage character set (UTF-8? ISO-something?)
- how this all works together.

I use nicEdit as javascript wysiwyg editor.

I could of course explain what happens whan I want to save ë and if that helps I will, but I figured it would be best to understand the matter instead of just trying to quick-fix it.

[EDIT]
To elaborate:

I use these in my PHP
    `$input = stripslashes($input); //(if magic quotes are 'on')`
    `$input = mysql_real_escape_string($input);`
    `$input = strip_tags($input, '<strong><em><span><ul><ol><p><a><br><li>');`

In my htmlpage:
    `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Javascript:
    `x = excape(x);`

Database:
    `MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci`
    `Table options: DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

This is an example of what happens:

I enter (inline) the word Rëg (using 'option+u' then 'e' on my mac).
I save the word. It shows like this: R�g on the webpage.
In the database i find Rëg.

I open the editor, do nothing but save again and it shows: R%uFFFDg in the database as well as on the page. After that it does not change anymore.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Kim

Comment: Commenting because it's not a complete answer, but: The escaping prior to database entry **must** be done server-side, not client-side. You can't trust anything coming from the client, even if you've put validation on the client-side.

Comment: Yes, utf-8 is a way to go. The rest can be solved eventually.

Comment: if you want to understand the matter, do not make a big mess of completely different matters. Database is one matter, HTML is other and AJAX is another. Take each one and figure out separately

Comment: ë is not weird and do not require any escaping. The only issue you may experience is AJAX response which can be easily decoded.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks for your remark, i indeed make use of some verification before putting stuff in my dB

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel If you know about a piece i can read to get the hang of it, i'd be happy if you tell me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *It shows like this: R�g on the webpage.*

You need to instruct the webbrowser that you're displaying the webpage in UTF-8 and that it should interpret it as the same. Add the following to top of your PHP, *before* emitting any character to the output:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Only the `<meta>` tag is not enough. This is not used by the webbrowser. It's the response header which counts. By the way, Javascript's `escape()` function is [**deprecated**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_Functions).

#### See also:

- [PHP UTF-8 cheatsheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet)

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I added the line just below the session_start() but still the ë is shown as diamond with questionmark.  And thatnks for the hint on deprecated function, i'll replace it.

Comment: And thanks again, BelusC :-) Replacing escape with encodeURIComponent did the trick.

Comment: Oh, you're submitting the form using JS? Btw, it's BalusC with an `a`, not `e`. And indeed, to mark a problem solved, you don't need to add some yelling to the question title, but just mark the most helpful answer accepted :) See also http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: LOL (i mean 'lol') i wasn't jelling, i was cheering from happiness, BalusC. Check is added, I'll change the title again...

Answer (score 0):

Just use UTF-8 for everything, and normally it will just work.

Comment: Hey Reinis, i do not know how to use UTF-8 for everything. I believe i read somewhere that javascript uses some ISO coding. How do i change that?

Comment: You can add a `charset="utf-8"` attribute to your external script elements to load them as utf-8. It's only required if you have unescaped string literals, though. CSS allows you to use `@charset 'utf-8';`, but this too is only required if you have unescaped string literals in your CSS, and it's rare. As for everything else, just set it to use UTF-8. Use an utf8 collation in MySQL, a `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8` header for HTML etc.

Comment: Thank you Reinis, i did all that already, as i described in my post above (the edited in part). It turned out that i used the wrong escape thingy in my javascript. Bah. But thanks again for your elaborate answer.